# execute exe in memory

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I was trying out this code.

[execute EXE from memory](http://www.coderprofile.com/networks/source-codes/138/execute-resource-directly-in-memory)

I am hitting on error "Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical"   . Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

```
......
   ReadProcessMemory(ProcInfo.hProcess, pointer(Context.Ebx + 8), @BaseAddress, 4, Bytes);    <-- error is here
.......

and

.....
   WriteProcessMemory(ProcInfo.hProcess, pointer(ImageNtHeaders.OptionalHeader.ImageBase), InjectMemory, InjectSize, Bytes);   <---- error here
......
```

I am using Delphi XE2 and windows 7 64 bit. Some of my friends are able to compile it under D7 environment. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just find out yourself? Look up online what kind of params ReadProcessMemory needs (or use Ctrl-Shift-Space to get the parameter list in Delphi) and check with your parameter types.

Comment: Can any one explain to me why anyone who is not writing viruses, and security exploits, would ever want to do any of this?

Comment: @WarrenP, I would use this e.g. for installer; you may extract the executable files from setup file's resources and run them without writing to disk. It will be much faster ;)

Comment: @WarrenP I am trying to create a wrapper module to protect my exe. Once it is wrapped up, i can apply some kind of packing techniques. Fro e.g. ASPack

Comment: I see. This does have non-evil uses then.

Comment: @TLama, an installer doesn't have to do things like this to be *faster*. It's an installer - it runs once typically, and saving a few seconds doesn't make a difference. Having your installer flagged as being malware or a virus does, however - "tricks" like this shouldn't be used for a routine purpose. I disagree with the asker wanting to do this on their own, too; there are reasons commercial software charges for accomplishing this, and since they've done all the work you should use them. If your app is important enough to need protection like this, it's important enough to be worth the money.

Comment: @Ken, I'm quite extremist in a performance point of view, but you're absolutely right; antiviral software didn't cross my mind. Fortunately I'm a satisfied InnoSetup user ;)

Comment: Thanks all for your invaluable comments. If you Look at way how UPX is executing compressed exe.. First, the original code is being decompressed into memory and then it gets executed. The same is true for most of the famous exe packers. ASPack also does the same, however, it has much better encryption and protection mechanism against crackers than what we have in UPX. Here we are not trying to execute a malicious code, instead we are trying to create a legal wrapper which works exactly same as UPX or ASPack. Hope this clarifies the scenario in a better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error tells you that one of the variables you are passing as parameter does not have the required type. The error is in a `var` parameter. The final parameter for both these functions is the only var parameter so clearly `Bytes` is not the required type.

The solution is to make `Bytes` match the type specified in the declaration of `ReadProcessMemory` and `WriteProcessMemory`. In XE2 that type is `SIZE_T`. So you just need to change your definition of `Bytes` to be of type `SIZE_T`.

Here are the XE2 declarations:

```
function ReadProcessMemory(hProcess: THandle; const lpBaseAddress: Pointer;
  lpBuffer: Pointer; nSize: SIZE_T; var lpNumberOfBytesRead: SIZE_T): BOOL; stdcall;
function WriteProcessMemory(hProcess: THandle; const lpBaseAddress: Pointer;
  lpBuffer: Pointer; nSize: SIZE_T; var lpNumberOfBytesWritten: SIZE_T): BOOL; stdcall;
```

Comment: Could the call just be changed like this: `ReadProcessMemory(..., SIZE_T(Bytes));`? That is, if the sizes of the two types are compatible.

Comment: @AndriyM Yes, but I would always prefer to avoid casting

Comment: Thanks David. It really helped and got compiled successfully.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank you, I was struggling with this a few weeks ago, finally just gave up, figuring I'd come back to it later...